# How to overwrite a file in the kubuntu package?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, lightdm

Everything started when I installed `ubuntu-desktop` on my kubuntu installation. Now it gives me the

> The system is running in low-graphics mode

error, so I've tried to edit the `lightdm.conf` file, but in my computer the `lightdm` directory doesn't exist.
I tried to install `lightdm-gtk-greeter` and `ubuntu-greeter`, but it keeps giving me this error because some program has unmet dependencies with another program.

I've tried a lot of things, but I can't find the way to fix it.

Comment: Sorry to say that but there's really not an easy way to solve it. Desktop environments are very complex "entities" with lots of packages tuned to work together seamlessly. Installing a different one is possible and usually the only caveat is bloot and duplicated tools (Kubuntu's KDE has its own set of system tools whereas Ubuntu's Unity use mostly Gnome tools). It didn't, however, caused the "low-graphics" error. Something else happened. Suggestion: Backup, reinstall and avoid playing with DEs.

Comment: Can you just 'apt remove ubuntu-desktop', or does it give errors?

Comment: @KyleH `ubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package, meaning it has no content itself and merely points to a (huge) list of packages to be installed. Removing the meta-package does not remove any of those packages. That's actually the main reason for my comment above. Once you install a *-desktop it's done, kaput. To reverse it you would need to know and remove all the packages installed for the DE as well as know what settings were changed and reverse them.